# Is there a way to track vuforia targets in a specific order?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia, event-tracking

I am trying to track vuforia image targets in a specific order so that the next target will not be trackable until the first one has been scanned.

Comment: well yes: Afaik they are not tracked if the according GameObject is inactive. So disable them all on start, after the first one is scanned enable the second one etc.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have set my other game object (holding my target) to disabled on load. I am trying to set it to active when a raycast picks it up. The raycast is working when I use debug log but I am getting errors trying to activate the game object. Have any ideas?

https://dotnetfiddle.net/pF7fZr

Comment: Yes! **Don't use `Find`**! [`Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) does **not** work for **inactive** GameObjects. Since for Vuforia all imageTargets have to be in the scene right from the beginning simply reference `SecondCube` already via the Inspector

Comment: My knowledge of C# is basic, how would go about this? I assume i would use Awake to .Find the object but how would I set it to active once the raycast conditions have been met?

https://dotnetfiddle.net/vXcc5z

Comment: now you are not storing the reference anywhere ... as said I would already reference it via the Inspector in the Unity Editor

Answer (score 0):

you should extend vuforia image target recognition and add like order variable. In your other script you can have static variable or currentTrackedOrder

```
public class VuforiaCustomBehaviour: MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler
{
   public TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;

   //order of image target
   public int order = 0;
   void Start()
   {
      mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
      if (mTrackableBehaviour)
      {
          mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
      }
   }

   public void OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus, 
   TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
   {
      if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
      newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
      newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
      {
          if (order == MainScript.currentTrackedOrder)
          {
              //Activate your object here
              DoSmth();
              MainScript.currentTrackedOrder++;
          }
       }
       else
       {
           OnTrackingLost();
       }
   }
}
```

So you can add this script to all image targets and put in order variable needed digits. Also you should disable default trackable events handler.